# Is there any reason WHERE NOT EXISTS does not seem to work in my statement?

Tags: sql-server

This is my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.KeyName
(
KeyNameID INT NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1),
PartName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
RwVersion ROWVERSION NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT PK_KeyName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KeyNameID)
);
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspKeyNameUpdate]
@KeyNameID INT,
@PartName VARCHAR(20),
@RwVersion BIGINT

AS

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
   DECLARE @newId INT = 0
   
      INSERT INTO dbo.KeyName(PartName) VALUES(@PartName)
      SELECT @PartName AS PartName
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT PartName FROM dbo.KeyName WHERE PartName = @PartName)

      SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

      IF ISNULL(@newId,0) != 0
         INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeName(KeyNameID,EmployeeID) VALUES(@newId,@KeyNameID)
END
```

The sp works if PartName does not exist in the KeyName table. However when I call it the second time with the same details it fails with the following error:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.KeyName' with unique index 'UX_KeyName'. The duplicate key value is (winston).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I replaced the INSERT block with the following:

```
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM KeyName WHERE PartName = @PartName)
      INSERT INTO KeyName(PartName) VALUES(@PartName)
      SELECT @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      INSERT INTO EmployeeName(KeyNameID,EmployeeID) VALUES(@newId,@KeyNameID)
```

The same error:

I am at sea currently, please help.

Comment: Your `EXISTS` has nothing to do with the problem; your error occurs on the `INSERT` (`INSERT INTO dbo.KeyName(PartName) VALUES(@PartName)`), not the `SELECT` statement immediately after it. As for the error, it's telling you the problem; you're trying to `INSERT` a value that is already in the table and that isn't allow due to a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the column `PartName`.

Comment: The way you have formatted your code leads me to believe that you have misunderstood the syntax. You can *either* use `insert ... values (...)`, *or* `insert ... select...`, but there is no `insert ... values ... select`. As it happens, the way you have written it is not a syntax error, because the SQL engine is running those as two completely separate statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that you think that the statements below are one statement:

```sql
      INSERT INTO dbo.KeyName(PartName) VALUES(@PartName)
      SELECT @PartName AS PartName
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT PartName FROM dbo.KeyName WHERE PartName = @PartName)
```

These are not 1 statement, they are **two**; an `INSERT` statement and a `SELECT` statement. If we terminate your statements, which you should be doing anyway as not doing so is deprecated, and add some additional formatting perhaps this becomes more clear:

```sql
      INSERT INTO dbo.KeyName(PartName)
      VALUES(@PartName);

      SELECT @PartName AS PartName
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PartName
                        FROM dbo.KeyName
                        WHERE PartName = @PartName);
```

As you can see, as a result the parameter, `@PartName` will *always* be `INSERT`ed into your table regardless of if it exists or not.

Likely you actually want something like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspKeyNameUpdate] @KeyNameID int,
                                         @PartName varchar(20),
                                         @RwVersion bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.KeyName WHERE PartName = @PartName)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.KeyName (PartName)
        SELECT @PartName;

        INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeName (KeyNameID,
                                      EmployeeID)
        VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @KeyNameID);
    END;
END;
```

Comment: I agree, but in his second query the if not exists should work to avoid the insert, or am I that mistaken ?

Comment: I don't follow your question there, @GuidoG .

Comment: The OP writes that if he replaces the insert with `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM KeyName WHERE PartName = @PartName)
      INSERT INTO KeyName(PartName) VALUES(@PartName)` he get's the same error. Should this "if not exists" not prevent the insert ?

Comment: I *am* using a `IF NOT EXISTS`, @GuidoG ... The `INSERT` can *only* take place if the value they are trying to `INSERT` does not already exist. If the above still results in the same error, i would suggest they have a poorly written trigger or similar.

Comment: I think you still don't understand my question. In the question of the OP he writes "if I replace the insert block with the following" and then he wrote another query that uses the `if not exists` at the same way you do, so why does he still get's the error there

Comment: *" i would suggest they have a poorly written trigger or similar"* @GuidoG . I can't account for information the OP doesn't provide.

Comment: Yes I agree, I think he is also not showing us all the code

Comment: @GuidoG - I would guess this is the usual thing where a question asker categorises *any* error as being "the same error" when they try a variant. Their `IF` guarded version doesn't wrap the intended statements in `BEGIN` and `END` so only the first `INSERT` is guarded, and I think they'll be getting a different error from the second `INSERT` (into `EmployeeName`) which is unconditional.

Comment: In the situation where the OP is getting the original duplicate error, the `PartName` already exists. Given that same context, In the rewritten version (without the `begin/end` as noted by Damien), the insert will not create a row, because the row already exists, so `scope_identity()` will be `null`, so `@newId` will be `null`, and then that  `null` is inserted into `EmployeeName`. I expect the second error is actually a "cannot insert the value null into column KeyNameId".

Comment: This has pretty much reduced my ignorance levels on INSERT....SELECT. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having trouble with the INSERT-SELECT syntax.

Try removing "VALUES(@PartName)" and it should be fine.

Comment: It needs the VALUES(@PartName).

Comment: @ChrisCatignani No, it doesn't.  `INSERT Table (val) SELECT 'val'` is valid SQL Server t-sql.

Comment: @squillman Ah...thanks for the correction.